# take special lines from txt database PHP

Tags: php, get, row, line, call

I have text database

```
0,Apple,Green
1,Banana,Yellow
2,Cherry,Red
```

and when I call `getdata.php?row=2` I need get data which is `2,cherry,red`

I am a bachelor in PHP and I have only one example ,
please help me for this problem.
thanks

```
$file_handle = fopen("./news.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  $parts = explode(',', $line_of_text);
  print $parts[0] . $parts[1] . $parts[2];
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To format a code block, you don't need `<br>` tags. Instead, highlight the code and click the `{}` editor toolbar button, or `ctl-k`. These will indent it 4 spaces, making a code block which gets free syntax highlighting based on the languages tagged.

Answer (score 0):

This would work and would also stop reading as soon as it found the right line (unlike the other answers who read the whole no file matter what)

```
    if (isset($_GET['row']))
    {
        $file_handle = fopen("./news.txt", "rb");
        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            if ($i == $_GET['row'])
            {
                $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
                $parts = explode(',', $line_of_text);
                print $parts[0] . $parts[1] . $parts[2];
                break;
            }
        $i++;
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to do this: if record number 2 is always on line number 3.

```
if (!isset($_GET['row']) || !is_int($_GET['row'])) {
    echo "please supply a row number";
    die;
}

$lines = file('news.txt');

// assumes record number 2 is on line 3
$row = $_GET['row'] + 1;

$parts = explode(',', $lines[$row]);
print $parts[0] . $parts[1] . $parts[2];
```

If record number 2 is not guaranteed to be on line 3

```
$row = $_GET['row'];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $row) === 0) {
        $parts = explode(',', $lines[$row]);
        print $parts[0] . $parts[1] . $parts[2];
        break;
    }
}
```

If the file is extremely large you will want to read line by line from a buffer.

```
$row = $_GET['row'];
if ($fp = fopen('news.txt', 'r')) {
    while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
        if (strpos($line, $row) === 0) {
            $parts = explode(',', $line);
            print $parts[0] . $parts[1] . $parts[2];
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to explode by rule with `explode("/n", $txt)` than you've an array of each rule. After you stored this explode in to a variable than you should explode a specific value again by `,`.